# Using Bluemix Secure Gateway app, I am receiving an error with finding destinations

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I am using a Secure Gateway app on Bluemix to create a secure gateway tunnel between a virtual machine and Bluemix. I have installed the secure gateway client on the virtual machine, and opened ports for applications. I have created a secure gateway and configured the destination details on Bluemix.

However, the Secure Gateway app is not connecting to the individual applications. On Bluemix, it is showing the following status for each destination: `Active Destinations: 0`

When I log onto the VM and connect to the secure gateway client I receive the following error messages:

```
[2016-04-05 20:37:04.577] [INFO] (Client PID 1) The Secure Gateway tunnel is connected
[2016-04-05 20:37:04.895] [ERROR] (Client PID 1) The server failed to bring up the destinations associated with this gateway
[2016-04-05 20:37:04.906] [INFO] (Client PID 1) The Secure Gateway tunnel was disconnected
[2016-04-05 20:37:04.906] [INFO] (Client PID 1) Secure Gateway tunnel connection retry in 5 seconds
[2016-04-05 20:37:09.909] [INFO] (Client PID 1) Secure Gateway tunnel connection retry in 5 seconds
```

How can I resolve this and complete setting up a secure gateway tunnel between the VM and the secure gateway app on Bluemix so that the application is externally accessible? Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming that you have followed steps mentioned in the page Configuring a secure gateway client to connect to Bluemix of IBM Secure Gateway Knowledge Center at  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SS9H2Y_7.2.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/sgclient_configuring.html  to do your configuration.  In the same knowledge center, please follow the instructions in the page 
Viewing connection status for secure gateway clients at http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SS9H2Y_7.2.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/sgclient_viewing-connections.html and let us know the connection status of the client

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions to configure the secure gateway client on this page: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/index.html. I installed the client using Docker. I then opened several ports using the following command:

Comment: Cont. acl allow [IP address]:8000 allow. This worked initially, however soon later I received the error message above. I looked at your link you gave me however I don't know where is the search field. On my Secure Gateway Dashboard it shows 4 destinations with each destination showing Active Connections: 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the Secure Gateway Server encountering some error while attempting to set up the listeners for your destinations, causing it to send a message to the client triggering the tunnel to disconnect.  While not ideal, this can typically be resolved by simply restarting the client.